# Can you change a css property for a specific page?

Tags: html, css, ruby, value-of-css-property

So I have a problem with my footer:
I have two pages which use specific position values and due to them being different to all the others, the footer when set to

```
position: absolute
bottom: 0
```

isn't sticking to the bottom and is buggy... for the 2 pages the footer will stick to the bottom when I use:

```
position: relative
    bottom: 0
```

so now I am asking if there is a way to change absolute to relative for the 2 specific pages?

THE FOOTER IS IN A SHARED FOLDER WHICH MEANS THAT IT IS AUTOMATICALLY PLACED INTO ALL PAGES

Comment: use inline  javascript and change css

Comment: You can also add different classes/ids for both page's body tags to identify them uniquely and then add CSS conditionally.

Comment: Using Inline Css is a best Option

Comment: @RushabhGandhi How does that work tho?

Comment: Are you generating the footer with php so they are identical on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the body depending of your current page to add css in specific cases :

```
.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.login .footer, .shop .footer{
    position: relative;
}
```

html :

```
<body class="login">
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline css for that pages like this:

page1:

```
<div style = "position: relative; bottom:0; ">
```

page2:

```
<div style = "position: absolute; bottom:0; ">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style = "position: absolute; bottom:0; ">
```

and For another tag

```
<div style = "position: relative; bottom:0; ">
```

**Using Inline CSS**

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to, to those two specific pages add one more class which has

`position: realtive; !important`

this way it will override the absolute positioning the base class has.

Comment: You don't have to add `!important` if you are more specific. For example, if you add `.important` to the `.footer` div, `.important.footer{}`will have the priority than just `.footer{}`.